# Can we get last commit message without cloning repo?

Tags: git

```
repo : https://repo/server/branch
```

In SVN, we get latest commit message by

```
svn log -l1 https://repo/server/branch
```

Similarly, In git

```
git clone https://repo/server/branch
git log -1
```

Can we get last commit message without cloning repo in git ?

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, question is about git only.

Comment: Usually git servers (github, gitlab) have a UI to view a repo and its commits; could you browse to the server?

Comment: Possibly relevant - https://superuser.com/q/341441/697166

Comment: An improvement, at least, is `git clone --single-branch --depth=1 <url>`